# D Forms Library TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: d, tablelayoutpanel

Every time I try to use the [D Forms Library](http://www.dprogramming.com/dfl.php), I run across the fact that it has no `TableLayoutPanel` -- which makes it practically impossible for me to make a good GUI.

Is there any `TableLayoutPanel` implementation out there for DFL?
How do people usually use this library without it?

#### Edit:

A link to another program that uses DFL would be a great bonus for an answer. :)

Comment: You haven't given any detail to you problem. What needs TableLayoutPanel... also if you are using D2 you'll need https://github.com/Rayerd/dfl which will need modification for 2.53.

Comment: @he_the_great: Confused at what you mean by "What needs TableLayoutPanel" -- I guess my question is, what *doesn't* need TLP? How do you make a GUI without it?

Comment: DFL has been used by many without much problem, so it would be odd to be missing something used by everything. What are you compiling? Are you able to build the library? Are you trying to use it in Linux? Are you using it with Tango? Did you install it correctly? You should give a compiler error since that is what tells people what went wrong.

Comment: @he_the_great: It **compiles fine**. That's not the issue. I just can't *use* it to lay out anything, because... well, how would I lay two things in a table layout? If you could provide a link to the source of program with a non-trivial DFL GUI, that would be an awesome thing to learn from.

Answer (score 6):

Posting as an answer because length exceeds comment length limit.

I downvoted your question because it is formulated with elements of flamebait. I would guess that your previous experience with GUI libraries was mostly with libraries supporting box layouts, such as Qt. The Win32 GUI API itself does not provide any primitives for creating box layouts - it uses absolute coordinates through and through. This remains unchanged in many OO libraries that build on top of the API, such as MFC. Some libraries, like VCL, have optional primitives for creating box layouts (panels with alignment and auto-size) - but in the end, all control repositioning has to be done by the application or the GUI framework, so something like this would need to be implemented in DFL from scratch.

So, to answer your questions:

> Is there any `TableLayoutPanel` implementation out there for DFL?

Probably not.

> How do people usually use this library without it?

They draw the controls on the form with a mouse, using Entice Designer. (The same is true for MFC/Visual Studio, VCL/Delphi IDE, etc.)

---

Reply to comment:

> how do I put things in a table layout (e.g. two side-by-side, and one below)?

I understand that you'd like to have a fixed-height panel at the bottom, and split the remaining space into two areas which both remain half the form's width when the form is resized.

1. In Entice Designer, place a Panel, set its `dock` to `BOTTOM`. Set its height appropriately.
2. Place a second panel, set its `dock` to `RIGHT`.
3. In your form's code, add the following method:

```cs
    protected override void onResize(EventArgs ea)
    {
        super.onResize(ea);
        panel2.width = this.clientRectangle.width / 2;
    }
```

As you can see, it can quickly get messy to get a more complicated "rubber table". I wouldn't bother, or if I really needed complex dynamic layouts, would look for another library.

> Or are you saying that's a bad idea in the first place?

Definitely not my point - the advantages of semantic layouts that don't *require* using an IDE to build are clearly visible. It's just that due to their Win32 API roots, Windows GUI libraries rarely provide good means to build them. Of course, their absence doesn't make building GUIs impossible or even hard - people simply usually go with fixed-size forms, etc. (This is clearly visible to end users switching from Windows to KDE - most KDE dialogs are resizable, while Windows' aren't.)

Comment: Yeah my previous experience has been with .NET and Java; I'm also familiar with the Win32 API, but I thought a library like this would definitely have a table layout.
I guess my question is, if I draw the form with a mouse with no layout panels, then how do I put things in a table layout (e.g. two side-by-side, and one below)? Or are you saying that's a bad idea in the first place?

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't say fixed size -- I needed it to automatically resize itself with the window (otherwise it could cover up the entire window if it's too small)... and like you said, that gets pretty messy. So there's pretty much no way to do this in DFL, right?

Comment: Just add the appropriate code in your form's `onResize` override. AFAIK, there is no way to do it without a resize handler in your code.

Answer (score 1):

in lack of a table layout you can use the location and size properties to position stuff on the board (and maybe even implement your own table layout)

you can use the [entice designer](http://www.dprogramming.com/entice.php) to make the gui and build further on the generated source

Answer (score 1):

Now that I'm near my code, there are two ways to manage layout. As mentioned by ratchet there is absolute positions and also docking. Docking places the item in 5 possible [locations](https://github.com/Rayerd/dfl/blob/master/win32/dfl/control.d#L76). The Top, Bottom, Left, Right, or Center (fill). You can then place a panel in one of these which can itself contain elements that are docked within it. You assign the docking value to the [dock property](http://wiki.dprogramming.com/DflDoc/Control#code-Control).

[Entice Designer](http://www.dprogramming.com/entice.php) is written with DFL.